# Nested subscribe rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

How to rebuilt this using rxjs if it is advisable:

```
constructor(private customerInfoService: CustomerInfoService) {
  customerInfoService.getCustomerIPById(this.a).subscribe(x => {
    customerInfoService.getIPActivityDates(x).subscribe(y => {
      this.latestActivityDate = y.latestDate;
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: zip ,combineLatest or flatMap, switchMap you can use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap). This allows you to "switch" the observable returned. So in your case, you could do something like:

```
customerInfoService.getCustomerIPById(this.a).pipe(
  switchMap(x => customerInfoService.getIPActivityDates(x))
}).subscribe(y => {
  this.latestActivityDate = y.latestDate;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    constructor(private customerInfoService: CustomerInfoService) {
  this.customerInfoService.getCustomerIPById(this.a)
    .pipe(
      concatMap(x => this.customerInfoService.getIPActivityDates(x))
    ).subscribe(y => {
      this.latestActivityDate = y.latestDate;
    });
}
```